# why keep Harker a prisoner in the castle?

Tags: dracula

In the Stoker Dracula novel why would Dracula keep Harker a prisoner in his castle, after  all of draculas deeds were signed? If harker returned, Dracula would not put himself in a bad situation or even arouse suspicion for himself. It seemed he had nothing to gain leaving him there to die. Was this  a novel plot hole perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

"Dead men tell no tales" Harker had seen too much for the Count to let him go free.

ch.4 *Jonathan Harker's Journal:*

> 19 May.—I am surely in the toils. Last night the Count asked me in the
>   suavest tones to write three letters, one saying that my work here was
>   nearly done, and that I should start for home within a few days,
>   another that I was starting on the next morning from the time of the
>   letter, and the third that I had left the castle and arrived at
>   Bistritz. I would fain have rebelled, but felt that in the present
>   state of things it would be madness to quarrel openly with the Count
>   whilst I am so absolutely in his power. And to refuse would be to
>   excite his suspicion and to arouse his anger. **He knows that I know
>   too much, and that I must not live, lest I be dangerous to him.** My
>   only chance is to prolong my opportunities. Something may occur which
>   will give me a chance to escape. I saw in his eyes something of that
>   gathering wrath which was manifest when he hurled that fair woman from
>   him. He explained to me that posts were few and uncertain, and that my
>   writing now would ensure ease of mind to my friends. And he assured me
>   with so much impressiveness that he would countermand the later
>   letters, which would be held over at Bistritz until due time in case
>   chance would admit of my prolonging my stay, that to oppose him would
>   have been to create new suspicion. I therefore pretended to fall in
>   with his views, and asked him what dates I should put on the
>   letters.
>  He calculated a minute, and then said, “The first should
>   be June 12, the second June 19, and the third June 29.”
>  I know now
>   the span of my life. God help me!

Also, just [for the evulz](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForTheEvulz) .